# How can i reference the DirectUpload js class from my jQuery block?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

My layout has:

```
//= require activestorage
```

Now in my jQuery I am trying to reference the DirectUpload class:

```
  // Instantiate the DirectUploader object
  const upload = new DirectUpload(file, url)
```

The direct upload class is here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activestorage/app/javascript/activestorage/direct_upload.js

I am currently getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: DirectUpload is not defined
>       at new:210

Comment: Open the Developer Console and start typing "DirectUpload" and see if it provides an autocomplete option. If it does not, I think it isn't being included properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reference the `DirectUpload` class using the `ActiveStorage` namespace.

For example,

`new class ActiveStorage.DirectUpload(...)`

Comment: It would be AWESOME if the Rails documentation mentioned this.  I'm finding the first iteration of ActiveStorage's documentation to be uncharacteristically poor for Rails.  The reason I became infatuated with Rails is the quality of its documentation.